# What's a fast (non-loop) way to apply a dict to a ndarray (meaning use elements as keys and replace with values)

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

At the moment I'm looping through like

```
new_data = [transform_dict[pt] for pt in line] for line in data]
```

But this is too slow. I've tried looking for a suitable `numpy` method but haven't found anything myself. Are there any matrix based implementations for this sort of thing?

Comment: Lastly every function you apply to your dataset will use some sort of loop operation. Even if you are using a matrix you will usually loop through all elements. In your example `replace` might be a good way to reduce runtime or you could preprocess your data.

Comment: Can you provide an example of a dictionary turned into an ndarray?

Comment: I'm not turning a dict into an ndarray, I'm replacing an ndarray with another ndarray using a dict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

transform your dictionary in array and use `np.take`:

```
Na=1000 #array
Nd = 10**4 #dict
data=randint(0,Nd,(Na,Na))
dic=dict(zip(range(Nd),randint(0,Nd,Nd)))
dicarray=np.array(list(dic.values()))
```

That is generally much faster :

```
In [3]: %timeit np.array([[dic[x] for x in line] for line in data]) 
1 loops, best of 3: 2.27 s per loop

In [4]: %timeit dicarray.take(data)
10 loops, best of 3: 24.4 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something that uses compiled `numpy` code.  But the problem is that there isn't any such code for accessing dictionary values.  It all has go through `dd[k]` or `dd.get(key)`.

`dd.items()` produces a list of key and value pairs.  You might be able to turn that into an array and play some `numpy` games with that.

`pandas` may have some ways efficiently turning a dictionary into a dataframe.

How big is this dictionary?  What kinds of keys and values?