# Improving performance of numpy mapping operation

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I have a numpy array of size (4, X, Y), where the first dimension stands for an (R,G,B,A) quadruplet.
My aim is to transpose each `X*Y` RGBA quadruplets to `X*Y` floating-point values, given a dictionary matching them.

My current code is as follows:

```
codeTable = {
    (255, 255, 255, 127): 5.5,
    (128, 128, 128, 255): 6.5,
    (0  , 0  , 0  , 0  ): 7.5,
}

for i in range(0, rows):
    for j in range(0, cols):
        new_data[i,j] = codeTable.get(tuple(data[:,i,j]), -9999)
```

Where `data` is a numpy array of size `(4, rows, cols)`, and `new_data` is of size `(rows, cols)`.

The code is working fine, but takes quite a long time. How should I optimize that piece of code?

Here is a full example:

```
import numpy

codeTable = {
    (253, 254, 255, 127): 5.5,
    (128, 129, 130, 255): 6.5,
    (0  , 0  , 0  , 0  ): 7.5,
}

# test data
rows = 2
cols = 2
data = numpy.array([
    [[253, 0], [128,   0], [128,  0]],
    [[254, 0], [129, 144], [129,  0]],
    [[255, 0], [130, 243], [130,  5]],
    [[127, 0], [255, 120], [255,  5]],
])

new_data = numpy.zeros((rows,cols), numpy.float32)

for i in range(0, rows):
    for j in range(0, cols):
        new_data[i,j] = codeTable.get(tuple(data[:,i,j]), -9999)

# expected result for `new_data`:
# array([[  5.50000000e+00,   7.50000000e+00],
#        [  6.50000000e+00,  -9.99900000e+03],
#        [  6.50000000e+00,  -9.99900000e+03], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: How many `rows` and `cols` are there?

Comment: @Will Many thousands for each.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36480358/whats-a-fast-non-loop-way-to-apply-a-dict-to-a-ndarray-meaning-use-elements

Comment: Would it be possible for you to create a code snippet that runs? The current code does not work, so it's hard to help you.

Comment: Will the second column always be -9999?

Comment: @karasinski No, that was just an example. The input data is, in fact, an arbitrary PNG image.

Comment: I _believe_ I've answered this question below. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that returns your expected result, but with such a small amount of data it's hard to know if this will be faster for you. Since I've avoided the double for loop, however, I imagine you'll see a pretty decent speedup.

```
import numpy
import pandas as pd


codeTable = {
    (253, 254, 255, 127): 5.5,
    (128, 129, 130, 255): 6.5,
    (0  , 0  , 0  , 0  ): 7.5,
}

# test data
rows = 3
cols = 2
data = numpy.array([
    [[253, 0], [128,   0], [128,  0]],
    [[254, 0], [129, 144], [129,  0]],
    [[255, 0], [130, 243], [130,  5]],
    [[127, 0], [255, 120], [255,  5]],
])

new_data = numpy.zeros((rows,cols), numpy.float32)

for i in range(0, rows):
    for j in range(0, cols):
        new_data[i,j] = codeTable.get(tuple(data[:,i,j]), -9999)

def create_output(data):
    # Reshape your two data sources to be a bit more sane
    reshaped_data = data.reshape((4, -1))
    df = pd.DataFrame(reshaped_data).T

    reshaped_codeTable = []
    for key in codeTable.keys():
        reshaped = list(key) + [codeTable[key]]
        reshaped_codeTable.append(reshaped)
    ct = pd.DataFrame(reshaped_codeTable)

    # Merge on the data, replace missing merges with -9999
    result = df.merge(ct, how='left')
    newest_data = result[4].fillna(-9999)

    # Reshape
    output = newest_data.reshape(rows, cols)
    return output

output = create_output(data)
print(output)
# array([[  5.50000000e+00,   7.50000000e+00],
#        [  6.50000000e+00,  -9.99900000e+03],
#        [  6.50000000e+00,  -9.99900000e+03])

print(numpy.array_equal(new_data, output))
# True
```

Comment: Your solution seems to work only for square input data, and does not work when `cols != rows`. But thanks for the ideas, I'll investigate. Anyway, speed is much more satisfying than my naive double-loop solution.

Comment: Fixed! This will now take the requested number of rows and columns.

Comment: Well, your code does not work for other data shapes. I've updated my initial message with a more complicated example. Your code returns correct results, but at the wrong position in the output array.

Comment: I updated my answer based off your new test data, but I'm still getting the correct results. Can you provide example data which causes my method to fail?

Comment: The example in my 1st message fails on my computer, with Python 2.7 (I've changed the unpacking `*key` into `key[0], key[1], key[2], key[3]`). I can't use Python3 right now because data is loaded using a library which is currently available only in Python2.

Comment: I've edited my response to be compatible with Python 2.7, but it still appears to produce the expected output. I'm not sure where to go from here. How is your output different from mine? I'm running Python 2.7.11, Numpy 1.11.0, and pandas 0.18.1.

Comment: With Python 2.7.6, Numpy 1.9.0, Pandas 0.13.1, I'm obtaining the following result, running your code: `[[5.5, 7.5], [6.5, 6.5], [-9999, -9999]] False`

Answer (score 1):

The [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author) contains a vectorized nd-array capable variant of list.index, which can be used to solve your problem efficiently and concisely:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
map_keys = np.array(list(codeTable.keys()))
map_values = np.array(list(codeTable.values()))
indices = npi.indices(map_keys, data.reshape(4, -1).T, missing='mask')
remapped = np.where(indices.mask, -9999, map_values[indices.data]).reshape(data.shape[1:])
```

Comment: Your solution seems to be working like a charm. Thanks! I'll discuss later on performance improvements.